# Documentum Document Content Share Location from SQL

Tags: oracle11g, documentum6.5

I am trying to sort out how to find the physical location of a file on a mapped documentum share. There are several ways to do it using the API or DQL, but neither of those will scale to what we need to migrate data out of the system. Ultimately the plan is to migrate all data out and into a new system, but we need the file locations to plan this out.

The following resources have been helpful:

https://robineast.wordpress.com/2007/01/24/where-is-my-content-stored/
https://community.emc.com/thread/51958?start=0&tstart=0

Running this DQL will give us the location, but the SQL provided does not return any data relevant to what we're trying to accomplish (or anything at all).

```
execute GET_PATH for '<parent_id_goes_here>'
```

Result:

```
t:\documentum\data\schema\storage_volume_number\00000000\80\01\ef\63.xlsx
```

Additionally, using the API with getpath returns valid data, but when choosing to show the SQL is gives the same query (a little further down) which doesn't actually give the location of the file.

```
API>getpath,c,<r_object_id>
...
t:\documentum\data\schema\storage_volume_number\00000000\80\01\ef\63.xlsx
```

This is the query provided with both when you choose 'Show the SQL'.

```
select a.r_object_id,    b.audit_attr_names, a.is_audittrail,
       a.event,          a.controlling_app,  a.policy_id,
       a.policy_state,   a.user_name,        a.message,
       a.audit_subtypes, a.priority,         a.oneshot,
       a.sendmail,       a.sign_audit
  from dmi_registry_s a, dmi_registry_r b
 where a.r_object_id = b.r_object_id and a.registered_id = :p0 and (a.event = 'all' or a.event = 'dm_all' or a.event = :p1)
 order by a.is_audittrail desc,   a.event         desc,
          a.r_object_id,          b.i_position    desc;
:p0 = < parent_id >;
:p1 = dm_getfile
```

The above query returns nothing in PL/SQL, and removing the :p0/:p1 variables just returns audit data.

Any guidance on how to get this using SQL, or a DQL script that could be written to give the path and r_object_id in a CSV to join? I'm also open to other ideas of pulling data out of this system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of digging I found that the best way to go about this is to convert the data ticket into your path. To quote the articles linked in the question:

> The trick to determining the path to the content is in decoding the data_ticket's 2’s complement decimal value.  Convert the data_ticket to a 2’s compliment hexadecimal number by first adding 2^32 to the number and then converting it to hex.  You can use a scientific calculator to do this or grab some Java code off the net.
>
> -2147474649 + 2^32 = (-2147474649 + 4294967296) = 2147492647
>
> converting 2147492647 to hex = 80002327
>
> Now, split the hex value of the data_ticket at every two characters, append it to file_system_path and docbase_id (padded to 8 bits), and add the dos_extension.  Viola! you have the complete path to the content file.
>
> C:/Documentum/data/docbase/content_storage_01/0000001/80/ 00/23/27.txt

This PowerShell code will do the conversion for you -- just feed it the data ticket.

```
$Ticket = -2147474649
$FSTicketInt = $Ticket + [math]::Pow(2, 32)
$FSTicketHex = [Convert]::ToString($FSTicketInt, 16)
$FSTicketPath = ($FSTicketHex -split '(..)' | ? {$_}) -join '\'
```

Then all you need to do is join the path with the content storage location using `[System.IO.Path]::Combine()`.